# How to select specified area in Python text

Tags: python

I want to select only cuttly link area ("https://cutt.ly/XJDV1G8") I tried RegEx but didin't make it happen. Below code, I tried to select ("") area but I need to select 8th of the ("") areas.

```
import re

text = '{"url":{"status":7,"fullLink":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/furkan_alkaya_","date":"2022-06-08","shortLink":"https:\/\/cutt.ly\/XJDV1G8","title":"Furkan Alkaya (@furkan_alkaya_) | Twitter"}}'

x = re.search(r"\b""\w+",text)

print(x.group())
```

Comment: I don't think `r"\b""\w+"` does what you think it does. If you evaluate it, you see it's `'\\b\\w+'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is JSON, so you should use the JSON library to process it:

```py
import json

text = '{"url":{"status":7,"fullLink":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/furkan_alkaya_","date":"2022-06-08","shortLink":"https:\/\/cutt.ly\/XJDV1G8","title":"Furkan Alkaya (@furkan_alkaya_) | Twitter"}}'
d = json.loads(text)
d['url']['shortLink']
```

Output:

```
'https://cutt.ly/XJDV1G8'
```

Comment: It worked!  I'm a new learner so hearing about these solutions makes me good. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

using the regex:

```
x = re.search(r'("shortLink":")(\w{5}:.{20})', text)
x[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

this will select the 8th of ("...") includes empty (""):

```
match = re.search(r'(?:"([^"]*)".+?){8}', text)
value = match[1] if match else None

print( value )
```